# throwing your own exceptions

Tags: java

I am new to Java and have been working on a converter that will take a dec number and convert it to binary and vice versa. i am wanting to implement exception handling, but am having difficulty understanding the concept fully. I want the program to catch a `NumberFormatException` and throw a `NotInBinaryException` that I have created in a separate class. I am able to throw the new exception but am uncertain on how to successfully catch the exception to display a `JOptionPane` that will display over the program prompting the user to input a number in binary format, while clearing the error and setting the focus on the text field where the error exists. So far this is the code that I have created. I would appreciate any help with getting me back on track.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class ImprovedBaseGui extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
 private JTextField txtBaseTen;
 private JTextField txtBaseTwo;
 private JButton btnBaseTen;
 private JButton btnBaseTwo;
 private JButton btnClear;
 public ImprovedBaseGui()
{
    this.setTitle("Base 10/2 Converter");    
    Container canvas = this.getContentPane();

    canvas.add(createCenterPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    canvas.add(createSouthPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setSize(475, 150);
    this.setLocation(800, 500);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(this.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

private JPanel createSouthPanel()
    {
        JPanel pnlSouth = new JPanel();

        btnBaseTen = new JButton("Base 10");
        btnBaseTen.addActionListener(this);
        btnBaseTen.setToolTipText( "Use to convert Base 2 to Base 10" );
        btnBaseTen.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        pnlSouth.add(btnBaseTen);

        btnBaseTwo = new JButton("Base 2");
        btnBaseTwo.addActionListener(this);
        btnBaseTwo.setToolTipText( "Use to convert Base 10 to Base 2" );
        btnBaseTwo.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        pnlSouth.add(btnBaseTwo);

        btnClear = new JButton("Clear");
        btnClear.addActionListener(this);
        btnClear.setBackground(Color.RED);
        pnlSouth.add(btnClear);

        return pnlSouth;
    }

private JPanel createCenterPanel()
    {
        JPanel pnlCenter = new JPanel();
        pnlCenter.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

        pnlCenter.add(wrapMeInAPanel(new JLabel ("Base 10")));
        txtBaseTen = new JTextField(16);
        txtBaseTen.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        pnlCenter.add(wrapMeInAPanel(txtBaseTen));

        pnlCenter.add(wrapMeInAPanel(new JLabel("Base 2")));
        txtBaseTwo = new JTextField(16);
        txtBaseTwo.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        pnlCenter.add(wrapMeInAPanel(txtBaseTwo));

        return pnlCenter;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      new ImprovedBaseGui();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

            if(e.getSource() == btnClear)
            {
                txtBaseTen.setText("");
                txtBaseTwo.setText("");
            }
            if(e.getSource() == btnBaseTwo)
            {
                try
                    {
txtBaseTwo.setText(Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(txtBaseTen.getText())));
                    }
                catch(NumberFormatException err)
                    {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, txtBaseTen.getText()+"");
                    txtBaseTen.setText("");
                    txtBaseTen.grabFocus();
                    }

            }
            if(e.getSource() == btnBaseTen)
            {
                try
                    {
txtBaseTen.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(txtBaseTwo.getText(), 2)));
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException err)
            {
            throw new NotInBinaryException();
                }

            }

        }

     private JPanel wrapMeInAPanel(Component c)
            {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.add(c);
                return panel;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only throw the `NotInBinaryException` if your method cannot handle the `NumberFormatException` from the binary parsing.  But it can handle it and you should handle it.  You don't need your `NotInBinaryException` here.

Just handle the `NumberFormatException` similar to how you handled it in your `txtBaseTen` case, although you may want to pick a more user-friendly error message for both.

```
try
{
    txtBaseTen.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(txtBaseTwo.getText(), 2)));
}
catch(NumberFormatException err)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, txtBaseTwo.getText()+"");
    txtBaseTwo.setText("");
    txtBaseTwo.grabFocus();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input. The solution you have given was how i had my code written initially. however for the the sake of learning to throw my own exception i was wondering how i can accomplish creating my own exception and have the NumberFormatException throw it instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using `NotInBinaryException`, then have another method perform the conversion for you, and have it throw a `NotInBinaryException`.  The `throws` clause is unnecessary if your `NotInBinaryException` is a `RuntimeException`.

```
private String getDecimalText(String binaryText) throws NotInBinaryException
{
    try
    {
        return Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(decimalText, 2));
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException err)
    {
        throw new NotInBinaryException();
    }
}
```

Then catch it in your `actionPerformed` method.

```
try
{
    txtBaseTen.setText(getDecimalText(txtBaseTwo.getText()));
}
catch(NotInBinaryException err)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Number entered was not in binary: " + txtBaseTwo.getText());
    txtBaseTwo.setText("");
    txtBaseTwo.grabFocus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your suggestion makes a lot of sense . I was trying to do this without using a method to handle the conversion and it just wasnt working. I guess I am just over thinking this way too much because it seems so simple when looking at it now.